# "Не" с причастиями и отглагольными прилагательными

Tags: орфография, грамматика

Расскажите, пожалуйства подробно, как пишется "не" с причастиями и прилагательными как полными, так и краткими (в особенности с теми, которые похожи на причастия, или как их еще называют иногда "отглагольными"). Очень большая путаница у меня по этому поводу.

Answer (score 3):

Частица "не" пишется слитно с прилагательными и полными причастиями:

1. слово  без  "не" не употребляется. Невинный, неразлучные друзья, ненавидящий, ненавидимый;
2. с приставкой  "недо": недооценный  художник, недочитанная книга;
3. если с причастием или прилагательным употреблены наречия  МЕРЫ  и СТЕПЕНИ (очень, весьма, совсем, почти, совершенно, полностью, крайне, абсолютно): мне попалась  совершенно  неинтересная книга; окраска делает  косулю  почти невидимой в лесу;
4. краткие формы прилагательных: история неинтересна, пирожок невкусен;
5. слова на -мый без "не" не употребляются: невообразимый, непобедимый, невредимый, незыблемый и т.д.

Раздельно:

1. "не" с относительными и притяжательными прилагательными: не весенний  день, не заячьи  следы;
2. с краткими прилагательными: не должен, не прав, не намерен, не согласен и др.;
3. если есть противопоставление: не настоящий, а  сказочный домик; не напечатанный текст,а  написанный от руки;
4. есть слова "далеко","вовсе", "отнюдь": отнюдь не близкое расстояние, вовсе не разгаданный кроссворд, далеко не приемлемое решение;
5. у причастия в полной форме есть зависимое слово: не решенная  мной  задача, не боящийся темноты человек;
6. причастия в краткой форме: яблоки не вымыты, трава не скошена утром;
7. есть отрицательное наречие или местоимение: никому не известные факты,никогда  не замерзающий родничок.

Answer (score 2):

**Частица "не" пишется слитно**:

- С полными причастиями без зависимых слов.
  Примеры:  *недописанное сочинение, несъеденный пирожок*.
- С причастиями и наречиями, оканчивающимися на "-о", если к ним относятся слова: совсем, совершенно, очень, весьма, крайне, чрезвычайно и т.д.
  Примеры:  *совсем недолго, очень нескоро, крайне недолго*.
- С отглагольными прилагательными на "-мый".
  Примеры: *невесомый, неведомый.*

**Частица "не" пишется раздельно**:

- С полными причастиями, если есть зависимые слова или противопоставление.
  Примеры: *"это не разбитая, а лишь треснутая ваза", "это не доеденный мной пирожок"*.
- С краткими прилагательными, которые не употребляются в полной форме.
  Примеры: *не рад, не готов*.
- С отглагольными прилагательными, оканчивающимися на "-мый", если есть зависимые слова или отрицательные местоимения.
  Примеры: *никаким средствами не досягаемая цель*.

Comment: А как отличить приставку "недо-" от частицы "не" с последующим словом, начинающимся на "до-"?