# Нужна ли запятая после "в результате" с зависимым словом?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после "в результате" с зависимым словом в следующем предложении:

> В результате удаления выбранных строк, узел учёта окажется непривязанным к адресу.

П. С.: подскажите ещё в комментариях по написанию слитно-раздельно *непривязанным*

Comment: Запятая не нужна. Уже был такой вопрос: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/16319/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%92-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, этот вопрос я видел, в нём нет зависимого слова "В результате (чего?) удаления"

Comment: *Не привязанная к дереву верёвка* (раздельно, есть зависимые слова), но *непривязанный конь* (слитно, нет зависимых слов). http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/677/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: Да, Вы правы, но от этого ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 1):

Выражения со словами *"в результате"* не обособляются, в том числе и при наличии зависимых слов. И [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_791) это подтверждает.

Comment: Спасибо, но и на грамоте написано "Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «в результате», ОБЫЧНО не обособляются". Можете привести контрпримеры, чтобы показать, что этот случай таковым не является?

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему она написала *обычно*, не могу придумать случаев с обособлением.

Comment: Можно сослаться на http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1 "Обычно обособляются обороты, которые содержат объяснение того, о чем говорится в предложении, и выделяются интонационно". Здесь как раз есть объяснение, да и интонационно хочется выделить.

Comment: По-моему, интонационно как раз этот оборот (в Вашем примере в частности) совсем не выделяется. По крайней мере совсем не так, как выделяются примеры там. И паузы никакой не хочется сделать.

Comment: >> *Я не понимаю, почему она написала обычно, не могу придумать случаев с обособлением* Допустим: В результате удаления выбранных строк и <длинное бла-бла-бла>, узел учёта окажется... Неужто не поставите запятую?! От распространённости оборота очень зависит.

Comment: Если я точно узнаю фразу (какое там бла-бла-бла), прочитаю её, тогда смогу сказать, что мне интуиция подсказывает, а теоретически рассуждать не могу.

Comment: *В результате удаления выбранных строк и невозможности их восстановления в дальнейшем, узел ....* Это еще не самое длинное. Как без запятой определить границу оборота?

Comment: Если могут быть варианты по смыслу, тогда нужна запятая, чтобы понятно было, что к чему, да. Об этом был какой-то вопрос.